# Remove table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following is my code

#### Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    })
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#table').remove('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    })
})
```

#### HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="click">click</div>
<div id="remove">remove</div>
```

When I add a row it works great, but I don't know how to delete the last row of the table. You can also check the online [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mZnR/).

How can I do this?

In addition, I want when the user also clicks on any row it will delete itself. I have tried out, but there is a problem. If you click on the row it is deleting itself, but when you add a row by clicking in #click then the row is not deleting itself by clicking on it.

Here is my code:

#### Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    })
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#table tr:last').remove();
    })
    $('#table tr').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

Comment: your script will not know which row to be deleted... bind the .on() event and then try..

Comment: I want to delete it with a particular item Id in a cell?

Answer (score 34):

If you want to remove the last table row of `#table`, you need to target it with your selector, and then call `$.remove()` against it:

```
$('#remove').on("click", function(){
    $('#table tr:last').remove();
})
```

Comment: For dynamic content make row id `unique` you can do it by appending something unique like this for php `<tr id="myTableRow<?php echo $id; ?>">` and same thing when you remove it :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove like that you have to specify which node you want to remove `$('#table tr:first')` and the remove it  `remove()`

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#table tr:first').remove();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mZnR/1/

Answer (score 2):

A demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/BfKSa/ **or** in case you are binding, add and delete to every row, this **different demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xuM4N/ come in handy.

API: remove => http://api.jquery.com/remove/

As you mentioned: This will delete the "delete the last row of the table"

`$('#table tr:last').remove();` will do the trick for your case.

#### Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>foo add&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    })
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#table tr:last').remove();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last `tr` from the table using the table class on button click.

```js
$('#remove').on("click", function(){
    $('.tbl tr:last').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the last row with a selector and the delete that row like that:

```
$('#table > tr:last').remove();
```

This will delete the last row in the table. What if you want to delete the first?

```
$('#table > tr:first').remove();
```

That's it. There is codeschool online course for jQuery. You will find lot's of valuable stuff there including selectors and DOM manipulation. Here is a link: http://jqueryair.com/

Answer (score 0):

If You want to remove row itself when click on table row then

```
$('table tr').on("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to add row on click of click button at the end of table

```
 $('#click').click(function(){
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>Xyz</td></tr>');
})
```