# Delete row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want the following functionality:

When the user clicks on any row it will get deleted.

I have tried the following, but there is a problem. If you click on the row it gets deleted fine, but when you add row by clicking on `#click`, the row is not getting deleted when I click on it.

Here's my code:

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
})
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#table tr:last').remove();
})
$('#table tr').click(function(){

$(this).remove();

});
})
```

Comment: why r u duplicating your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662691/remove-table-row-using-jquery

Answer (score 4):

[`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click) just forwards to [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind), and `bind` only binds to what matches the elements in the jQuery object *at the time of creation*. You probably want to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) with its `selector` parameter:

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/hug5H/) on JSFiddle.**

Answer (score 1):

You shoud bind a click handler to each row using [on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) (tr)

> .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements

```
$('your-table').on('click','tr',function(){
   $(this).remove();        
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/UQTfS/)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not assigning the event to the appended row. Try appending the row like this:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    $('#table tr:last').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```